# how to input multiple data form and one of form is upload image in one page

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

i have sample code
form 1

```
<form> //form 1
<input type=text name=text1>
<input type=text name=text2>
<input type=text name=text3>
</form>
```

i need save the upload file first to database
form upload

```
<form enctype="multipart/form-data">
<input type=file[] name=file1>
</form>
```

is form 2

```
<form> form //2
<input type=hidden name=file_data value="<?php image_data_array ?>">
<input type=text name=text4>
<input type=textarea name=text5>
<input type=checkbox name=text6>
</form>
```

then i will post form1 and form2 to database in one button

```
<form>
<input type=submit name=submit>
</form>
```

anyone can help me?

Comment: Why not just wrap everything in the same form?

Answer (score 0):

If you forms are located in same webpage. ADD two different form tags all together in one form.

So you can achieve  it or if the forms are in different page store the values in session from first page to second page while adding the data insert into combine session and forms values into insert statement.